# Install4j: How exclude launcher in function of installation type

Tags: install4j

I have 2 installation types in installer: Full and Custom

By default, `install4j` copies all launchers in destination directory in 2 installation types.

In Custom installation type, I want to **exclude** some `launchers`. How can I archive this task ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the "Installation type" screen, you choose different installation components for different installation types. By putting the launchers into different installation components, you can deselect those components in the custom installation type.